# Liferay 7 - Export / Import - DLFileEntryImpl cannot be cast to FileEntry

Tags: java, liferay

I am implementing export / import / staging to my application.
In my stagedModelDataHandler, I want to export references to a DLFileEntry. Here is what I do :

```
StagedModelDataHandlerUtil.exportReferenceStagedModel(portletDataContext, stagedModel, stagedModel.getImageId(), PortletDataContext.REFERENCE_TYPE_WEAK);
```

Where stagedModel.getImageId() returns a DLFileEntry.

The problem is that I got this error when trying to export :

```
ERROR [liferay/background_task-1][BackgroundTaskMessageListener:164] Unable to execute background task
com.liferay.exportimport.kernel.lar.PortletDataException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.impl.DLFileEntryImpl cannot be cast to com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.FileEntry
```

When I look at how export is implemented in Liferay code base, it seems to be done the same way than me.

What can I do to fix it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I was using DLFileEntry instead of FileEntry !

Comment: Ok, so the title of your question is what I've answered, missed that the exception had the other message, containing FileEntry..